# Coefficient of a term using binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, multinomial-coefficients

I was just wondering how would I find the coefficient of any term let's say $x^3$ in the expansion of $(x^2+2x+2)^{10}$ using binomial expansion or any other technique. Please let me know if this can be found directly using a shortcut if any.

Comment: You can refer to the Wikipedia page on "Multinomial theorem".

Comment: Alright, I'll just check it now.

Comment: [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

We can also apply the binomial theorem *twice* in order to determine the coefficient of $x^3$ in $(x^2+2x+10)^{10}$.

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
[x^k](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^3](x^2+2x+2)^{10}&=[x^3]\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}{k}x^{2k}(2x+2)^{10-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{1}\binom{10}{k}[x^{3-2k}]\sum_{j=0}^{10-k}\binom{10-k}{j}(2x)^j2^{10-k-j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^1\binom{10}{k}\binom{10-k}{3-2k}2^{10-k}\tag{3}\\
> &\binom{10}{0}\binom{10}{3}2^{10}+\binom{10}{1}\binom{9}{1}2^9\tag{4}\\
> &=1\cdot120\cdot1024+10\cdot9\cdot 512\\
> &=168960
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *[binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement)*
- In (2) we observe that only $k=0$ and $k=1$ may contribute via $x^{2k}$ something for the coefficient of $x^3$. So, we change the upper limit of the sum to $k=1$. We apply the *coefficient of* operator rule
  \begin{align*}
  [x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)
  \end{align*}
  and we also expand the inner binomial according to the binomial formula.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $x^{3-2k}$ by selecting the summand with $j=3-2k$.
- In (4) we expand the sum.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\pars{x^{2} + 2x + 2}^{10} =
\sum_{a,b,c\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 0}}{10 \choose a,b,c}
\bracks{a + b + c = 10}x^{2a}\,\pars{2x}^{b}\,2^{c}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{a,b,c\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 0}}{10 \choose a,b,c}2^{b + c}
\bracks{a + b + c = 10}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{n = 2a + b}x^{n}
\end{align}

---

$$
\bracks{x^{n}}\pars{x^{2} + 2x + 2}^{10} =
\sum_{a,b,c\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 0}}{10 \choose a,b,c}2^{b + c}
\bracks{a + b + c = 10}\bracks{n = 2a + b}
$$
The sum restrictions let to write $\ds{a}$ and $\ds{b}$ in terms of $\ds{c}$ and $\ds{n}$. Namely,
$\ds{a = n + c - 10}$ and $\ds{b = 20 - 2c - n}$:
$$
\bracks{x^{n}}\pars{x^{2} + 2x + 2}^{10} =
\sum_{c\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 0}}{10 \choose n + c - 10,20 - 2c - n,c}
2^{20 - c - n}
$$
$\ds{c}$ bounds are determined by:
$$
a = n + c - 10 \geq 0\,,\quad b = 20 - 2c - n \geq 0
\implies 10 - n \leq c \leq 10 - n/2
$$

---

\begin{align}
&\bracks{x^{n}}\pars{x^{2} + 2x + 2}^{10} =
\sum_{c = m}^{M}{10! \over \pars{n + c - 10}!\pars{20 - c - n}!c!}\,
2^{20 - c - n}
\\[5mm] = &\,\,\,
\bbox[#ffe,20px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\left. 2^{20 - n}\sum_{c = m}^{\left\lfloor 10 - n/2\right\rfloor}
{10 \choose c}{10 - c \choose n + c - 10}2^{-c}\right\vert_{\ n\ \leq\ 20}}}
\qquad\mbox{where}\qquad m = \max\braces{0,10 - n}
\end{align}
Note that the above expression vanishes out when
$\ds{\quad n <0\quad \mbox{o}\quad n > 20}$.

> For instance: When $\ds{n = 3}$,

\begin{align}
&\bracks{x^{3}}\pars{x^{2} + 2x + 2}^{10} =
2^{17}\sum_{c = 7}^{8}
{10 \choose c}{10 - c \choose c - 7}2^{-c} =
2^{17}\bracks{{10 \choose 7}2^{-7} + 2{10 \choose 8}2^{-8}}
\\[5mm] & =
120 \times 2^{10} + 45 \times 2^{10} = \bbx{168960}
\end{align}